# ionic pull to refresh doesn't work in latest version 1.2.1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, pull-to-refresh

I followed the tutorial to create a [demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qug9JdsugH0) to show "Pull to refresh" and "Infinite scroll". But the **Pull to refresh** doesn't work at all because it always go directly to hyperlink instead refreshing every time when I try to Pull to refresh.

My html:

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
    <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <ion-refresher pulling-text="Pull to refresh"
      refreshing-text="Loading..."
      refreshing-icon="ion-loading-c"
      pulling-icon="ion-ios7-arrow-thin-down"
      on-refresh="loadNewerStories()">
    </ion-refresher>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="story in stories track by story.id" href="{{story.url}}">
        <img ng-src="{{story.thumbnail}}" ng-if="story.thumbnail.startsWith('http')">
        <h2 class="story-title">{{story.title}}</h2>
        <p>
          <span am-time-ago="story.created_utc" am-preprocess="unix"></span>
          - {{story.domain}}
        </p>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <ion-infinite-scroll
      on-infinite="loadOlderStories()"
      distance="5%">
    </ion-infinite-scroll>
  </ion-content>
```

My javascript:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])    
.controller('AppCtrl',function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.stories = [];

    function loadStories(params, callback) {
      $http.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/new/.json',{params : params})
        .success(function(response) {
          var stories = [];
          angular.forEach(response.data.children, function(child) {
            stories.push(child.data);
          })
          callback(stories);
        });
    }

    $scope.loadOlderStories = function() {

      var params = {};
      if ( $scope.stories.length > 0 ) {
        params['after'] = $scope.stories[$scope.stories.length - 1].name;
      }
      loadStories(params, function(oldStories) {
        $scope.stories = $scope.stories.concat(oldStories);
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
      });
    };

    $scope.loadNewerStories = function() {
      var params = {'before': $scope.stories[0].name};
      loadStories(params, function(newerStories) {
        $scope.stories = newerStories.concat($scope.stories);
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
      });
    }

});
```

What should I do? Thanks.

**P.S.**: It will be fine if I remove href in ion-item.

Comment: Can you create a wroking plunker?

Comment: Even not able to register to plunker. Tried Safari, Google Chrome.